# utm in token [current-page:url]

Tags: 8, tokens

For a specific type of urls on my website I'd like to add an `utm` on opengaph URL, so I can track social activity on those URLs.

The token I'd like to modify is: `[current-page:url]`.

I've tried:

`[current-page:url?utm_source=share-freemium&utm_medium=shares&utm_campaign=shares-free]`

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help?